# foreach loop not working when iterating over object properties from an array of objects [javascript]

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I have a variable 'layerArr' that contains and array of objects. each with their own properties.

I wish to loop through the 'absoluteEndM' property of every object to check to see if its value is greater than the value of sctrLength and then do something depending on the answer. I have tried the following:

```
       LayerArr[i].absoluteEndM.forEach(function (endMtr)
        {
            if (endMtr > sctrLength) {
                maxWidth = endMtr;
            }
            else {
                maxWidth = sctrLength;
            } 
        })
```

and

```
       for (var i = 0; i < LayerArr.length; i++) {
            if (LayerArr[j].absoluteEndM > sctrLength) {
                maxWidth = LayerArr[j].absoluteEndM;
            }
            else {
                maxWidth = sctrLength;
            } 
        }
```

neither work and I am not sure why. What is the correct way to do this? thanks

EDIT: layerArr contains the following objects:

layerArr[0] , LayerArr[1], LayerArr[2] and LayerArr[3]  (they are just numbered, no name)

each of those have a bunch of properties for example:

```
layerArr[0].endDate
layerArr[0].cracked
layerArr[0].absoluteEndM
etc...
```

and:

```
layerArr[1].endDate
layerArr[1].cracked
layerArr[1].absoluteEndM
etc...
```

Comment: Please share your array of objects

Comment: where is `sctrLength` and `maxWidth` declared ... the logic looks all sorts of wrong by the way - and the two loops are doing completely different things

Comment: `absoluteEndM` seems to be a number. So... Why do you think a number has a `.forEach()` method?

Comment: @Andreas - or ... is it an array, and why would you compare it with a number :p

Comment: `LaterArr.forEach(layer => console.log(layer))`

Comment: The `for` loop is pointless here. `maxWidth` will be set based on the last item of `LayerArr` array

Comment: @Jarmomanda X ,  maxwidth and sctrLength are declared, I just didn't add that to the above

Comment: @Andrea , I have an array of objects (layerArr[0], layerArr[1], layerArr[2] etc.). Each of those objects have an 'absoluteEndM' property which is a number. I want to check the value of absoluteEndM for each LayerArr[i] object to see if it is greater than sctrLength

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it is a number, I want to compare that number with sctrLength, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: if `LayerArr[j].absoluteEndM` is a number, then clearly it won't have a `.forEach` method ... so `LayerArr[i].absoluteEndM.forEach` would give you an *error*, no?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't see why not. LayerArr[0].absoluteEndM might be 6, LayerArr[1].absoluteEndM might be 10 etc... each layerArr[i] will have a different number under the absoluteEndM property.

Comment: You're saying the `absoluteEndM`  property is both a number (because it could have a value of 6 and 10) **and** have the forEach method ... because your code has `.absoluteEndM.forEach` ... so `LayerArr` is an array and because it is an array, any objects in that array somehow have the `forEach` array method too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const layerArr = [
    { absoluteEndM: 2 },
    { absoluteEndM: 4 },
    { absoluteEndM: 1 }
]

const sctrLength = 3;
let maxWidth = 0;

for (let layer of layerArr) {
    maxWidth = layer.absoluteEndM > sctrLength ? layer.absoluteEndM : sctrLength
    console.log(maxWidth)
}
```

This snippet should work (ES6, you might have to transpile it to ES5 or do some work yourself).

But the functionality of the code itself is a little weird, you actually get one value in `maxWidth` which isn't representative. You can make an array like this:

```
const maxWidths = layerArr.map(layer => layer.absoluteEndM > sctrLength ? layer.absoluteEndM : sctrLength)
console.log(maxWidths)
```

A demonstration:

```js
const layerArr = [
 { absoluteEndM: 2 },
 { absoluteEndM: 4 },
 { absoluteEndM: 1 }
]

const sctrLength = 3;
let maxWidth = 0;

// Start of example 1 - just setting the maxWidth
for (let layer of layerArr) {
 maxWidth = layer.absoluteEndM > sctrLength ? layer.absoluteEndM : sctrLength
 console.log(maxWidth)
}
// End of example 1

// Start of example 2 - making an array of maxWidths
const maxWidths = layerArr.map(layer => layer.absoluteEndM > sctrLength ? layer.absoluteEndM : sctrLength)
console.log(maxWidths)
// End of example 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I run this it gives an error on the "of" in "for (let layer of layerArr)"

Comment: Can you give some more information about the error?

Comment: it just says "expected ';'", I have of course added the ; but it's made no difference

Comment: You probably need to replace `for (let layer of layerArr)` with `for (var i = 1; i < layerArr.length; i++)` and `layer.` references `layer[i].`. The code is written in the newest "version" of JS, it might be that your runtime doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked, I just had to change it slightly to: for (var i = 1; i < layerArr.length; i++) {
                maxWidth = layerArr[i].absoluteEndM > sctrLength ? layerArr[i].absoluteEndM : sctrLength;
            }

Comment: Actually scratch that, it doesn't work in all situations as it loops through the code 3 times, each time replacing what just happened. This is the code that worked, you might want to update the answer: maxWidth = sctrLength; for (var i = 1; i < layerArr.length; i++) {
                maxWidth = layerArr[i].absoluteEndM > maxWidth ? layerArr[i].absoluteEndM : maxWidth;
            }

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to tell exactly what you need from your question, but it seems that what you're looking to do is ascertain the max value for `absoluteEndM` from an array of objects, but also including the value of `sctrLength`. Here's how that might look:

```js
const LayerArr = [
  {
    absoluteEndM: 2,
  },
  {
    absoluteEndM: 4,
  },
  {
    absoluteEndM: 1,
  },
]

const sctrLength = 3

const maxWithDefault = defaultValue => items => Math.max(...[...items, defaultValue])
const maxIncludingSctrLength = maxWithDefault(sctrLength)
const path = k => x => x[k]
const getAbsoluteEndM = path('absoluteEndM')

const getMaxAbsoluteEndM = _layers =>
    maxIncludingSctrLength(_layers.map(getAbsoluteEndM))

const result = getMaxAbsoluteEndM(LayerArr)

console.dir(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure if you have understood correctly though, sorry if I was not clear enough. I have an array of objects (layerArr[0], layerArr[1], layerArr[2] etc.). Each of those objects have an 'absoluteEndM' property which is a number. I want to check the value of absoluteEndM for each LayerArr[i] object to see if it is greater than sctrLength. (see edited notes above)

Comment: @NickyLarson I'm struggling to see what about the code would not solve the problem you have. In the code above, `LayerArr` is an array of objects with an `absoluteEndM` property. The code above checks each `absoluteEndM` value, and `sctrLength`, and returns the largest value. Perhaps you could explain further?

Comment: @NickyLarson my code gives the same result as the accepted answer so I'm struggling to see where the issue is with this one

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why but it is telling me there is a syntax error on: const maxWithDefault = defaultValue => items => Math.max(...[...items, defaultValue])

Comment: The code snippet obviously works when i run it in the browser, so I'm not sure why it won't work for me

Comment: @NickyLarson if the other code works for you then there's no need to worry, my confusion was to whether or not this did indeed solve the problem. The syntax in the code above is relatively new to js, so it may be that where you are trying to run it, there is an issue with support for that feature of the language